# Запятая. Нужна?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, синтаксис

*Ваша живопись не серая(,) и это прекрасно!*

Нужна запятая? Почему? Какие здесь члены предложения?

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Ваша живопись не серая, и это прекрасно!***

Запятая ставится в **сложносочиненном** предложении (ССП) перед союзом И.

**В первом предложении** предикативная основа: *живопись не серая.* Сказуемое составное именное, связка *быть* пропущена, именная часть выражена прилагательным.

**Во втором предложении** предикативная основа: *это прекрасно.* Подлежащим является местоимение *это.* Сказуемое составное именное, связка *быть* пропущена, именная часть выражена кратким прилагательным (в форме ср.рода).